# Suggestion to rig & animate skin+bone+muscle at the same time?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Good morning,

I have a human arm model with separate skin, muscle and bone meshes. Is there anyway I can rig and animate the human arm with skin, muscle and bone together? If not, any suggestions how to make this right and fast?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the skin mesh is low or mid-poly:

1. Rig the skin with bones (automatic or manual weight painting).
2. Control the muscles inside the skin with **Mesh Deform** modifier set to skin object.
3. Parent the bone meshes to rig bones, they do not need to deform.

If the skin mesh is highpoly (ie. scanned or sculpted mesh):

1. Build a low poly envelope around your arm.
2. Control both the skin and muscles through *Mesh Deform* driven by the low poly.
3. Parent the bone meshes to rig bones.

The Mesh Deform modifier will ensure that the muscles will stay inside the skin and will deform correctly. You can add shapekeys to the muscles and skin to make them flex and preserve volume.

It is difficult to weight paint multiple meshes to the same bones to have the same deformation. The automatic heat-driven weigh painting will fail on separate meshes - this works well only on volumetric auto-weight painting that Maya has.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the skin will always be together with the muscles and bones, you could link them all as the same object, then add an armature to your model for animation.

Answer (score 0):

It's very probable, that it will be hard to get perfect deformations during animation, on all 3 layers of tissue by joining them in one mesh and simple parenting them to Armature (although if an artist prepared it for animation then it's not impossible).
If you won't get desired effect with this easy solution, then I recommend to parent mesh bones to rig bones as usual and for deforming muscles, use arm shaped lattice parented to rig and finally for skin would work simple parented to rig bones, if not, use lattice, if not add Shrinkwrap modifier with Keep Above Surface enabled and offset above zero.